# Apache not using PHP5-FPM despite successful installation

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

I managed to successfully install php5-fpm

```
xxx@xxx:/etc/apache2/conf-available$ a2enmod actions fastcgi alias 
Module actions already enabled
Module fastcgi already enabled
Module alias already enabled
xxx@xxx:/etc/apache2/conf-available$ a2enconf php5-fpm 
Conf php5-fpm already enabled
```

However, despite having successfully install php5-fpm and enabled it, phpinfo() shows that i am still using Apache 2.0 Handler as its SAPI.

Any ideas as why is this happening ?

Cheers...

Comment: Have you disabled the php5 module, restart apache?

Comment: @frz3993 ah.. thanks for reminding me, i guess it's a rookie mistake. Please write that as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache has a module called `PHP5`. Should you need to use php-fpm, you will need to disable that module and restart apache. Example

```
a2dismod php5
service apache2 restart
```